# Rewrite URL in AngularJS Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, ionic-framework

The app I'm developing allows users to change the IP of the server (where the REST API is). This address is stored in a variable that can change, but the problem is that when the services are instantiated, the base URL cannot be changed. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345165/change-the-base-url-for-a-resource) I was able to change the url of some of the services, but I can't do the same for those who have POST actions.

I've tried several configurations, but there's always a problem. For example, this:

```
// Services file
app.factory('Bookings', BookingsFactory)

function BookingsFactory($resource, GlobalVariables) {
    return $resource('http://:url/api/bookings/:id/', null, {url: '@url'});
}

//Controllers file
Bookings.save(booking, {url: GlobalVariables.IPServer});
```

Throws this error message "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED", because the request URL is not correct: "http://api/bookings/?end_time=2015-06-30T09:30&name=Reunion&room=1&start_time=2015-06-30T09:43&started=true".

If I call it like this:

```
//Services file
app.factory('Bookings', BookingsFactory)

function BookingsFactory($resource, GlobalVariables) {
    return $resource('http://:url/api/bookings/:id/', {url: '@url'});
}

//Controllers file
Bookings.save({booking: booking, url: GlobalVariables.IPServer});
```

I get a 400 BAD REQUEST error, and the response asks for content for all the required fields: "This field is required."

I'm using AngularJS v1.3.13. Is there a way to change the base URL in every petition with this approach, even on POST requests? Or even better, is there a way to update the URL in every factory of the application after the app is started?

Answer (score 0):

In an app that I work on I use the $rootScope to hold my base server URL for all requests. I don't know if that's a good way to use $rootScope or not, but what's for sure is that the app is working.

oops sorry I forgot to also add that I can change the base URL while the app is running, which is what you need.

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't work for me. I'm using services that I then inject in the controllers, so I think that these services are instantiated when the app is served and therefore cannot be changed once the app is started. I tried with rootScope but it didn't work because of this.

Comment: You know services can accept arguments when called did you try sending the server URL as an argument to the functions?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, it's on the examples in my question. I don't know if my problem is with the order of these arguments, because it crashes when I'm doing a POST request...